# Will a solid double 2x8 or spliced 7.25" LVL support more weight?

Tags: beam

What's going to support more weight spanning 15':

A double 2x8 or a double 7.25 LVL that's put together with two 11' pieces matched with two 4' piece?  The LVL will be joined with glue and 1/2" thru bolts.

Comment: You're not going to get a 15' LVL's performance with the splice that you seem to intend. Just stack up plies of #2 grade 2x8s until you get the performance you need.

Comment: Recalling your other question, you've basically got a 15 ft wide house with a carrier beam running down the center. You would size such a carrier beam with Table R602.7(2) under [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7). That table would fit your situation perfectly if each of your joists were cut vertically on top of the carrier beam, so the tabulated spans are conservative. Interpolating in that table, I get a 10'-4" span length with single jack studs if you're using 4 plies of 2x8.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that anyone can answer your question without knowing what kind of load this will be supporting. Is it a roof ridge-beam? If so, what's your snow load? Is this an opening in a 1st floor wall with a 2nd floor above it? If so is it load bearing or not? There are far too many variables for you to trust the good intentions of well meaning strangers on the internet who are making guesses based on the very minimal you've provided.

Comment: Additionally, it's not really about supporting _more_ weight, but about supporting _enough_ weight to do the job.

Comment: @FreeMan, from his other question, this is under a kitchen with 15' floor joists that are too squishy for his liking. Granted, the literal question is insufficient for a rational answer.

Comment: Links to the "other question" should be supplied if that's where the additional detail is, @popham. If someone wants free help, he should do as much as possible to make it as easy as possible for others to provide that help, as opposed to "just knowing" all the background. :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

A splice effectively halves the capacity of an otherwise solid two-component joist. When splices are used, additional plies must also be used to regain capacity, keeping the unspliced section up to the total load task. Therefore, the doubled 2x8 with no joints will be stronger than a spliced two-ply engineered lumber unit.

That said, overall strength isn't the only concern. You also need to have reasonably low levels of *bounce*. A 2x8 at 15' is a bit of a noodle. You'll want to examine deflection tables for whatever you end up planning to use. That span generally calls for a taller joist.

Comment: I recall the joists also were 2×8's spanning 15'. Same grade and species, then, you can take the number of joists and use that for the number of plies in your beam to double the floor stiffness. Halve the number to get 150%. Etc.